# View Thumbnails of images in a Document Library - SharePoint 2007

Tags: picture-library, document-library

I know that in SharePoint 2007,  every image inside a [Picture Library] can have a thumbnail by adding the (_t) folder and the _extension.jpg to the file name.

What about if my images are stored inside a [Document Library]? is there a way to display thumbnails of those images (of course without having to download them all :))

I am working on a thumbnail view application and my images are all stored inside a Document Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this isn't possible.  The picture library has additional code that allows for the thumbnail preview.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Document library doesn't create thumbnails of images. You can easily migrate all your images to a picture library. Just open both libraries in Explorer view and drag-and-drop them from document to picture library.